# Display Date with time in JTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

I'm using JTable(for the first time) in my MVC application and want to display a Datetime column that need to display date and time.
I am able to display the date. Here is how the column looks like in the JTable definition.

```
 AssignedDate: {
                title: 'Assigned Date',
                width: '15%',
                type: 'date',
                displayFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
```

How would I display the time? 
I know I need to change the type and displayFormat - but have no idea what to change those to.

Comment: Can you give a reason why you downvoted this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following are the options:

1. try setting the `displayFormat: 'dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss'` I have my
   doubts if this works because when i read the jtable documentation
   they were mentioning about having no time field. never mind give it
   a shot.
2. Straightforward (but not the best) way in case you are just showing
   the date and no editing is required convert the date into string at
   the server side and show it in column`type: 'text'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried the first one and doesn't seem to work. I have gone with the second one as no other option comes up to my mind.

Answer (score 4):

**STEP 1** :put this code at the bottom of jquery.jtable.js then save it:

```
 /************************************************************************
 * DATETIME extension for jTable                                         *
 *************************************************************************/
(function($) {

    //Reference to base object members
    var base = {
        _createInputForRecordField: $.hik.jtable.prototype._createInputForRecordField,
        _getDisplayTextForRecordField: $.hik.jtable.prototype._getDisplayTextForRecordField
    };
//extension members
$.extend(true, $.hik.jtable.prototype, {

    /************************************************************************
     * OVERRIDED METHODS                                                     *
     *************************************************************************/

    /* Creates an input element according to field type.
     *************************************************************************/
    _createInputForRecordField: function (funcParams) {
            var fieldName = funcParams.fieldName,
            value = funcParams.value,
            record = funcParams.record,
            formType = funcParams.formType,
            form = funcParams.form;

        //Get the field
        var field = this.options.fields[fieldName];

        if (field.input || field.type != 'datetime'){ // If not a datetime field, call base method
            return base._createInputForRecordField.apply( this, arguments );
        }

        //If value if not supplied, use defaultValue of the field
        if (value == undefined || value == null) {
            value = field.defaultValue;
        }
        return this._createDateTimeInputForField( field, fieldName, value );
    },

    /* Gets text for a field of a record according to it's type.
     *************************************************************************/
    _getDisplayTextForRecordField: function (record, fieldName) {
        var field = this.options.fields[fieldName];

        if (field.display || field.type != 'datetime') { // If not a datetime field, call base method
            return base._getDisplayTextForRecordField.apply( this, arguments );
        }
        var fieldValue = record[fieldName];

        return this._getDisplayTextForDateTimeRecordField(field, fieldValue);
    },

    /************************************************************************
     * PRIVATE METHODS                                                     *
     *************************************************************************/

    /* Creates a date input for a field.
     *************************************************************************/
    _createDateTimeInputForField: function (field, fieldName, value) {
         var $input = $('<input class="' + field.inputClass + '" id="Edit-' + fieldName + '" type="text"' + (value != undefined ? 'value="' + this._getDisplayTextForDateTimeRecordField(field, value) + '"' : '') + ' name="' + fieldName + '"></input>');
        $input.datetimepicker({
            stepMinute: 10
        });
        return $('<div />')
            .addClass('jtable-input jtable-date-input')
            .append($input);
    },

    /* Gets text for a datetime field.
     *************************************************************************/
    _getDisplayTextForDateTimeRecordField: function (field, fieldValue) {
        if (!fieldValue) {
            return '';
        }

        var displayFormat = field.displayFormat || (this.options.defaultDateFormat + ' ' + this.options.defaultTimeFormat);

        var date = this._parseDate(fieldValue);
        return date.format( displayFormat );
    }

});

})(jQuery);
```

**STEP 2**: declare the jtable field you want to use datetimepicker like this:

```
 time_of_call: {
                    title: 'time_of_call',
                    type: 'datetime',
                    displayFormat: 'dd-mm-yy HH:MM:SS TT'
                },
```

**STEP 3** :make sure you use the most up-to-date jquery libs in your html:

```
   <link href="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="jtable/themes/lightcolor/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jtable/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a solution to 2 points for displaying in text format by @Lakshman

```
 AssignedDate: {
                title: 'Assigned Date',
                width: '15%',
                display: function (data) {
                            var nowDate = new Date(parseInt(data.record.RequestedOn.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, '')));
                            return [nowDate.getMonth() + 1, nowDate.getDate(), nowDate.getFullYear()].join('/') + ' ' +
[nowDate.getHours(), nowDate.getMinutes(), nowDate.getSeconds()].join(':');
                        },
                create: false,
                edit: false
            },
```

which gives you '05/07/2019 10:52:21' formate date, hope this helps you to customize more.